# Rails application servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, performance, server

I've been reading information about how different rails application servers work for a while and some things got me confused probably because of my lack of knowledge in this field. Anyway, the following things got me confused:

1. `Puma` server has the following line about its `clustered mode` workers number in its readme:

   > On a ruby implementation that offers native threads, you should tune this number to match the number of cores available

   So if I have, lets say, 2 cores and use `rubinius` as a ruby implementation, should I still use more than 1 process considering that `rubinius` use native threads and doesn't have the lock thus it uses all the CPU cores anyway, even with 1 process?

   I understand it that I'd need to only increase the threads pool of the only process if I upgrade to a machine with more cores and memory, if it's not correct, please explain it to me.
2. I've read some articles on using `Server-Sent Events` with `puma` which, as far as I understand, blocks the puma thread since the browser keeps the connection open, so if I have 16 threads and 16 people are using my site, then the 17th would have to wait before one of those 16 leaves so it could connect? That's not very efficient, is it? Or what do I miss?
3. If I have a 1 core machine with 3Gb of RAM, just for the sake of the question, and using `unicorn` as my application server and 1 worker takes 300 MBs of memory and its CPU usage is insignificant, how many workers should I have? Some say that the number of workers should be equal to the number of cores, but if I set the workers number to, lets say, 7 (since I have enough RAM for it), it will be able to handle 7 concurrent requests, won't it? So it's just a question of memory and cpu usage and amount of RAM? Or what do I miss?

Comment: Yes on (3). 7 Unicorn workers taking 300MB each will use 2.1GB. Unlike a threaded server, e.g. Puma or Sidekiq, they don't share memory.

Comment: ThsYou should probably ask these as 3 separate questions btw.